# Python Choice Not In List

Tags: python

```
while True:

print "Please choose from one of the five following options:"

print " 1. 10^1\n 2. 10^2\n 3. 10^3\n 4. 10^4\n 5. 10^5\n"
    choice = raw_input()

    if choice == 1:
        print "1"
    elif choice == 2:
        print "2"
    elif choice == 3:
        print "3"
    elif choice == 4:
        print "4"
    elif choice == 5:
        print "5"

    while choice not in [1,2,3,4,5]:
        print "Not a valid choice!\n"
        break
```

What syntax should I be using? I keep getting not a valid choice. Its like Python is placing every choice even 1,2,3,4,5 in the list of points outside of that list.

Comment: Your while-loop is unnecessary.  Put it in an else-clause in your if-statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the `raw_input` to an int:

```
choice = int(raw_input())
```

the type of `choice` from `raw_input` will be a `str` which is why there are no matches, so you need to either change all your `if` to compare with the character or convert choice to an `int`

**EDIT**

In light of the comments, it would be better to change your comparison's to compare against the single character string, for one this is what you're intending anyway, and secondly it protects against invalid conversions for instance if you enter an input value that cannot be cast to an `int` then this will throw an exception so I'd modify your code to this:

```
choice = raw_input()

if choice == "1":
    print "1"
elif choice == "2":
    print "2"
elif choice == "3":
    print "3"
elif choice == "4":
    print "4"
elif choice == "5":
    print "5"

while choice not in ["1","2","3","4","5"]:
    print "Not a valid choice!\n"
    break
```

Comment: Thanks @EdChum! Still learning Python basics. I appreciate it!

Comment: A better solution in this case is probably to test against strings, since otherwise the program will barf if the user enters a non-integer. You could trap that, of course, but easier to just test against strings to begin with!

Comment: @kindall yes I agree which is why I suggested modifying the `if` condition checking

Comment: @StevenRumbalski fair enough, I think it's a valid point that the casting will fail on non-convertable inputs so I've edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would use a dict, check if the key/choice is in the dict, if it is print the choice and break else print the `"Not a valid choice!\n"` message:

```
# map choice to whatever you want to print

d = {"1": "1", "2": "2", "3": "3", "4": "4", "5": "5"}
while True:
    choice = raw_input("Please choose from one of the five following options:\n"
                       "1. 10^1\n 2. 10^2\n 3. 10^3\n 4. 10^4\n 5. 10^5\n")
    # if the key is in the dict, the choice is valid
    # so print the choice value and break.
    if choice in d:
        print(d[choice])
        break
    # if we get here choice was invalid
    print "Not a valid choice!\n"
```

There would be no point converting choice to an int, leave it as a string and do the lookup on the `dict` also using strings as keys. You can store whatever value you want for each choice as a value in the dict.

Answer (score -1):

```
while True:

   print "Please choose from one of the five following options:"

   print " 1. 10^1\n 2. 10^2\n 3. 10^3\n 4. 10^4\n 5. 10^5\n"
choice = raw_input()

if choice == 1:
    print "1"
elif choice == 2:
    print "2"
elif choice == 3:
    print "3"
elif choice == 4:
    print "4"
elif choice == 5:
    print "5"

else:
    print "Not a valid choice!\n"
```

this should be the easiest fix